# sql - Select multiple substrings from same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have column(name-xml) value from message table as below (in XML format)

```
<Line>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <ErrorText>sky is red</ErrorText>
</Line>
<Line>
    <ID>54321</ID>
    <ErrorText>roses are white</ErrorText>
</Line>
<Line>
    <ID>98765</ID>
    <ErrorText>Sun rises in the east</ErrorText>
</Line>
```

From here I need data as below

```
ID      ErrorText
12345   sky is red
54321   roses are white
98765   Sun rises in the east
```

I need 2 separate columns from the same DB table column.
How

Comment: Which database are you using and what version? Answers will be product dependent.

Comment: Why on earth are you storing data like this? Wouldn't it be better to instert in into a table with a couple of columns? Eg. ErrorText, LineId, etc. I can provide you with an MSSQL script for this but it will be slow for large sets of data

Comment: it's Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.5500.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXmlColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
(
N'<Line><ID>12345</ID><ErrorText>sky is red</ErrorText></Line><Line><ID>54321</ID><ErrorText>roses are white</ErrorText></Line><Line><ID>98765</ID><ErrorText>Sun rises in the east</ErrorText></Line>'
);

SELECT ln.value('(ID/text())[1]','int') AS ID
      ,ln.value('(ErrorText/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ID
FROM @mockup m
CROSS APPLY m.YourXmlColumn.nodes('/Line') A(ln);
```

`CROSS APPLY` allows you to call the native XML.method `.nodes()`. The `XPath` "/Line" will return each repeating `<Line>`-element as a separate row. The method `.value()` allows you to pick the element's content.

### UPDATE

An example how to cast the deprecated `TEXT` type. I use a CTE to do the cast.

```
WITH casted AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,CAST(CAST(t.YourXmlColumn AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML) AS ToXml
    FROM YourTable t
    --WHERE...  (filters go here)
)
SELECT ln.value('(ID/text())[1]','int') AS ID
      ,ln.value('(ErrorText/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ID
FROM casted
CROSS APPLY casted.ToXml.nodes('/Line') A(ln);
```

Comment: This is working if I execute it as it is.. But i need to use insert into @mockup select XML from message  and then execute the last query. When i am doing this, I am getting empty rows. For what it's worth, the XML column in my table is of the data type Text but not XML

Comment: @Shyama I don't know if I get this correctly... You do not have to use my *mockup-table* at all. Just use your original table and column name in the same place. And about `TEXT`: This type is deprecated since v2005!. In computer thinking this means *centuries*. You will need a `CAST` to `VARCHAR(MAX)` and from there you can further `CAST` to `XML`. You really should try to use the native XML type if this is under your control. This will be faster and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '
    <Line>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <ErrorText>sky is red</ErrorText>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <ID>54321</ID>
        <ErrorText>roses are white</ErrorText>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <ID>98765</ID>
        <ErrorText>Sun rises in the east</ErrorText>
    </Line>'

SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.value('ID[1]', 'INT') ID
    ,Tbl.Col.value('ErrorText[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') ErrorText
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('//Line') Tbl(Col)
```

Comment: I am using somthing like this, but I am getting Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used. Please help. DECLARE @XML XML = (select  XML  from message where XML like '%<Status>1</Status>%' and xml like '%ErrorText%' and TYPE='Response')

SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.value('ID[1]', 'INT') ID
    ,Tbl.Col.value('ErrorText[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') ErrorText
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('//Line') Tbl(Col)

Comment: This query maybe return more than one row and It,s depend on your data.

Comment: You must limit your output by where clause or use Top 1 in select statement.